# Can someone help me read this crash report used quarkxpress in yosemite.?

Tags: software

```
Process:               QuarkXPress [7709]
Path:                  /QuarkXPress 8/QuarkXPress.app/Contents/MacOS/QuarkXPress
Identifier:            com.quark.QuarkXPress
Version:               8.0 (8.0)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           QuarkXPress [7709]
User ID:               504

Date/Time:             2015-02-25 12:33:19.344 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        52FD42AB-4DA8-A17C-A080-819B5C0EA25D


Time Awake Since Boot: 3500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000021

VM Regions Near 0x21:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000001948000 [ 25.3M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /QuarkXPress 8/QuarkXPress.app/Contents/MacOS/QuarkXPress

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: retain


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9b4030a7 objc_msgSend + 23
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x933a33d1 CFBundleCopyLocalizedStringForLocalization + 1505
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9327920f CFBundleCopyLocalizedString + 47
3   com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 0x954510ee PJCCreateLocalizedPaperName2 + 740
4   com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 0x9545bdc9 OpaquePMPaper::GetLocalizedNameFromBaseName() + 35
5   com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 0x95476c34 PMPaperGetName + 47
6   com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0025ffaf PSJobOutput::InjectPPDFeatures() + 509
7   com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x002607aa PSJobOutput::MakePSSetup() + 126
8   com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x002626d4 PSJobOutput::OpenJob() + 110
9   com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0021b479 JobOutput::AutoOpenJob::AutoOpenJob(JobOutput&) + 61
10  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0021bd1c JobOutput::Output(ProgressRef__*) + 182
11  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0036cbc3 PrintOutputMedia::DoOutput(DocRef__*, JobRef__*) + 787
12  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x00d4d19c OutputMediaBridge<PrintJobSettings>::OutputCB::Handler(XTOutputRec*) + 60
13  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x002ecc68 BaseCB::CBHandler(void*, unsigned long) + 56
14  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x009e4f0e xtdocallback + 428
15  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x009e5681 xtcallback + 597
16  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0021a0a8 PrintMgr::Output(DocRef__*, Job&) + 212
17  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0022bd90 XTOutput(DocRef__*, OutputMediaRef__*, long) + 248
18  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0017ddcc DoCommandMacCore(long, unsigned char&, unsigned char&, bool, bool, ScrollBox&) + 2818
19  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x00183476 DoCommand(unsigned long, bool) + 270
20  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x00cdb144 CMD_Menu::Do() + 80
21  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x00cb7595 CMD_Queue::Do() + 165
22  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x0041ac78 docommand(long) + 40
23  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x001b867a XPressCmdHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 508
24  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a96624 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948e0651 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2291
26  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948df62c SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
27  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948f2e65 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
28  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a964a2 SendHICommandEvent(unsigned long, HICommand const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned char, void const*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, OpaqueEventRef**) + 447
29  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x949571fc SendMenuCommandWithContextAndModifiers + 72
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x949571a8 SendMenuItemSelectedEvent + 207
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x9495706c FinishMenuSelection(SelectionData*, MenuResult*, MenuResult*) + 145
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94aedc96 MenuSelectCore(MenuData*, Point, double, unsigned long, OpaqueMenuRef**, unsigned short*) + 775
33  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94aee3de MenuSelect + 162
34  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a99e58 HIMenuBar::HandleMouseEvent(OpaqueEventRef*) + 96
35  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a99c56 HIMenuBar::HandleEvent(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*) + 60
36  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948e0caf HIObject::EventHook(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 163
37  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a96624 _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
38  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948e0651 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2291
39  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948df62c SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
40  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948f2e65 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
41  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94913b30 ToolboxEventDispatcherHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 3294
42  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948e0a1b DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 3261
43  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948df62c SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
44  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x948f2e65 SendEventToEventTarget + 88
45  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a95d05 ToolboxEventDispatcher + 82
46  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94a95bc9 RunApplicationEventLoop + 240
47  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x001b17d4 main + 200
48  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x00001fba _start + 216
49  com.quark.QuarkXPress           0x00001ee1 start + 41

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9726d8ce kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9aef973f _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 245
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x9aef93a2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9726d8b2 kevent + 10
1   libQLogger.XC.r.dylib           0x0821ceea MonitorConfigFileChanges(void*) + 428
2   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x900e943a PrivateMPEntryPoint + 68
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ede13 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954edd89 _pthread_start + 162
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ebe52 thread_start + 34

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9726ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ee2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ebe2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9726c512 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954eeabe _pthread_cond_wait + 842
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954eece1 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x9011d2f6 TSWaitOnConditionTimedRelative + 167
4   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x9011ce55 TSWaitOnSemaphoreCommon + 499
5   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x9011d050 TSWaitOnSemaphoreRelative + 24
6   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x900fd31c TimerThread + 93
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ede13 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954edd89 _pthread_start + 162
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ebe52 thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9726ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ee2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ebe2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9726ce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ee2b1 _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x954ebe2e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x163230b0  ebx: 0xa068a194  ecx: 0x9b42223b  edx: 0x00000001
  edi: 0x9320019e  esi: 0x163230b0  ebp: 0xbfffc528  esp: 0xbfffc508
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x9b4030a7   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000021

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 7067
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=439.8M resident=229.9M(52%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=209.9M(48%)
Writable regions: Total=240.5M written=34.1M(14%) resident=59.2M(25%) swapped_out=4K(0%) unallocated=181.3M(75%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
ATS (font support)                 33.4M
CG backing stores                  4404K
CG image                             16K
CG shared images                   1136K
CoreGraphics                          8K
CoreServices                        344K
CoreUI image data                   220K
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             63.6M
MALLOC (admin)                       48K
Memory Tag 242                       12K
Memory Tag 249                      156K
OpenCL                               32K
Stack                              66.6M
VM_ALLOCATE                       117.8M
__DATA                             34.8M
__IMAGE                             528K
__IMPORT                            868K
__LINKEDIT                        173.2M
__OBJC                             3436K
__TEXT                            266.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                       712.6M
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                               1.4G

Model: iMac8,1, BootROM IM81.00C1.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.29f1
Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 2600 Pro, ATI Radeon HD 2600 Pro, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR2 SDRAM, 800 MHz, 0x7F7F7F7F7F9B0000, 0x4354324732533830304D2E4D3136464D0000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 2 GB, DDR2 SDRAM, 800 MHz, 0x7F7F7F7F7F9B0000, 0x4354324732533830304D2E4D3136464D0000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8C), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.36.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: ST3320820AS_Q, 320.07 GB
Parallel ATA Device: PIONEER DVD-RW  DVR-K06A
USB Device: EPSON Scanner
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Optical USB Mouse
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix: Update to QuarkXPress 10.5

Nothing below is guaranteed to work in Yosemite.
QuarkXPress 8 is only supported up to Snow Leopard.

*Reference:* http://forums.quark.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=4608

Personal experience - QuarkXPress 9 doesn't work either in Yosemite, I just had to update too.